Numerical radius norm is equivalent to the operator norm
Currently, I am studying numerical ranges and numerical radius of linear operators. As one of the references, I am studying the book ``Numerical Range: The Field of Values of Linear Operators and Matrices" by Karl E. Gustafson and Duggirala K.M. Rao. In page $9$, there is a theorem which states that the numerical radius norm is equivalent to the operator norm whenever the basespace is a Hilbert space. I have met with the following understandings:
Let $\mathbb{X}$ be a Banach space and $L(\mathbb{X})$ be the collection of all bounded linear operators on $\mathbb{X}$. We denote $S_{\mathbb{X}}$ as the unit sphere of $\mathbb{X}$ and $X^*$ is the dual of $X$. Let $T\in L(\mathbb{X})$ the numerical radius of $T$ defined as:
$$ w(T)=\sup \{ |x^*(Tx)|:x\in S_{\mathbb{X}}, x^*\in S_{\mathbb{X}^*}, x^*(x)=1 \}. $$
On the other hand, the operator norm is defined as:
$$ \Vert T \Vert = \sup \{ \Vert Tx \Vert:x\in S_{\mathbb{X}} \}. $$
In general, the numerical radius does not form a norm (rather, it forms a seminorm).
Now my query is: whenever the numerical radius forms a norm in $L(\mathbb{X})$, is it still equivalent to the operator norm in $L(\mathbb{X})$? One side is easy as,
$$ |x^*(Tx)|\leq \Vert Tx \Vert \implies w(T)\leq \Vert T \Vert. $$
What about the other inequality? Can we conclude that both things are equivalent or not? Please help me or provide me any references where these things are discussed in the context of Banach spaces. Thank you in advance.

I would first look at the case where $X$ is smooth so that $w(T) = \sup_{|x|=1} \langle j(x),Tx \rangle$ where $j \colon X \to 2^{X^*}$ is the duality mapping, or even when $X$ is uniformly convex.  You have to consider complex spaces only since, even in the Hilbert space setting, you can have a nonzero operator $T$ such that $(Tx,x)=0$ for all $x$. Then for the constant sequence $T_n=T$ you have that $w(T_n)=0$ but $|T_n|=|T|>0$.

@EvangelopoulosFoivos Thank you for your comment on this. I am totally new in this topic. Can you please elaborate a little more?

I do not have something to elaborate on, it is just a guess that if your claim were to hold, the Banach space would need to have "nice" properties that Hilbert spaces do. The first thing that comes to mind is uniform convexity but I am not sure if it can lead anywhere...

If $X$ is a complex Banach space, then $w(T)\ge \|T\|/4$ (a Theorem of Lumer if I remember correctly): First let $w(T)\not=0$.
It is known that the spectral radius $r(T)$ satisfies $r(T) \le w(T)$
(the boundary of the spectrum $\sigma(T)$ is always contained in the closure of the numerical range). Hence $F(\lambda):=(I-\lambda T)^{-1}$ is defined and analytic on $|\lambda| < 1/w(T)$ since ($1/w(T)\le 1/r(T)$), and (Neumann series)
$$
F(\lambda)= \sum_{k=0}^\infty \lambda^k T^k \quad (|\lambda| < 1/w(T)).
$$
Now let $x \in X$ with $\|x\|=1$, and let $x^\ast$ be any functional with $\|x^\ast\|=1$ and $x^\ast(x)=1$. For $|\lambda| \le 1/(2w(T))$ we get
$$
\|x-\lambda Tx\| \ge |x^\ast(x-\lambda Tx)|=|1-\lambda x^\ast(Tx)| \ge 1-|\lambda| |x^\ast(Tx)| \ge 1- \frac{1}{2w(T)}w(T) =\frac{1}{2}.
$$
Hence
$$
\forall x \in X ~ \forall |\lambda| \le \frac{1}{2w(T)}: ~~ \|(I-\lambda T)x)\| \ge \frac{\|x\|}{2},
$$
so
$$
\forall x \in X ~ \forall |\lambda| \le \frac{1}{2w(T)}: ~~ \|x\| \ge \frac{\|F(\lambda)x\|}{2},
$$
which yields
$$
\forall |\lambda| \le \frac{1}{2w(T)}: ~~ \|F(\lambda)\| \le 2.
$$
With this inequality Cauchy's integral formula for the path $\gamma(t)=e^{it}/(2w(T))$ $(t \in [0,2\pi])$ yields
$$
T=F'(0) = \frac{1}{2\pi i} \int_\gamma \frac{F(\xi)}{\xi^2} d\xi,
$$
so
$$
\|T\| \le  \frac{1}{2\pi} \cdot (2\pi \frac{1}{2w(T)}) \cdot 2 \cdot (2w(T))^2
= 4w(T).
$$
In case $w(T)=0$ the observations above show that $F$ is analytic on $\mathbb{C}$ with $\|F(\lambda)\|\le 1$, hence $F$ is constant by Liouville's theorem, which forces $T=0$.
Edit: I found the paper of Lumer again (see Theorem 5): https://community.ams.org/journals/tran/1961-100-01/S0002-9947-1961-0133024-2/S0002-9947-1961-0133024-2.pdf

Thank you for the detailed proof. It definitely helps me a lot.
